# on zooming out to 25% in chrome the elements in the div are going out of the bounds (not staying within the div)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

i have created a simple signup webpage.when i reduce the zoom percentage to 25% in chrome total arrangement is lost.I tried to use percentage but it is not working properly.i tried it in many ways.but i did not get.so please help me with this i'm a beginner.

[Demo of the situation @fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saimadanmohan/X5F5j/)

code-html

```
<body onload="fill()">
    <div id="page">
        <div class="central">
            <h2 class="signup">Sign Up...</h2>
        <table  border="2" class="forum" cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="10px;" >
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <input type="text" value=" first name" class="opac"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value=" last name" class="opac"/>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" value=" email" size="50" class="opac"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" value=" contact number" size="50"class="opac"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Birthday</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="2" class="dates" cellpadding="4px" cellspacing="5px" >   
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="month">Jan</option>
                        <option value="month">Feb</option>
                        <option value="month">Mar</option>
                        <option value="month">Apr</option>
                        <option value="month">May</option>
                        <option value="month">Jun</option>
                        <option value="month">Jul</option>
                        <option value="month">Aug</option>
                        <option value="month">Sep</option>
                        <option value="month">Oct</option>
                        <option value="month">Nov</option>
                        <option value="month">Dec</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="days">
                        <option value="day">31</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="years">
                        <option value="year">2000</option> 
                    </select>
                </td>
            <tr>

        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>



#page
{
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    background-color:#b3dced;
    height:900px;
    width:1100px;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    background-image:url('limericki.png');
    //background-position:top;
    background-size:40px 40px;
}

.central
{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:60%;
    margin-top:5%;  
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    height:400px;
    width:400px; 
    border-radius:10px;
    //border-width:40px;
    padding:10px;
    background-image:url('pattern.jpg');
    background-position:top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 60px;  
}

.forum/*form class*/
{
    margin-top:20%;
    margin-left:3%;
    //padding:20px;
}

.opac/*opacity inside the text boxes*/
{
    opacity:0.6;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-width:3px;
    border-style:double; 
}

.dates
{
    margin-top:-1%;
    margin-left:3%;
}

.dates td
{
    //height:30px;
    width:80px;
}

.signup
{
    position:absolute;
    top:1%;
    left:25%;
    z-index:1;
    color:White;
 }
```

Comment: can some on help me with css indentation i tried but i was unable to do

Comment: I fixed the indentation.

Comment: thanks a lot from next time i will try do it

Answer (score 0):

Sincerely, they are already out of bounds on 100% and I'm using Chrome on Gnome (Debian). Have you considered responsiveness?

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) might be what you want, albeit it's a completely different thing.

Ok, I have looked at your CSS. The problem is this:

- you fix the `#page` size to 1100px;
- you set the `margin-left` of `.central` to 60%;
- fixed (px) and proportional (%) metrics don't always go well with one another.

The easiest thing you can try is:

- remove `left-margin` from `.central`;
- add `right: 50px` to `.central`;
- don't constraint `.central` so much but let it fit the content.

Comment: i'm on win8.1 and anything greater than 50% zoom is working fine and even on fiddle it is the same.btw i did not down vote your answer.

Comment: Ok no qualms about that. But consider that Windows 8.1 is not the only platform. You have many platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac) and browsers (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, IE). Unless you are embedding the HTML in CEF you shouldn't fixate on chrome and this means whatever you do now will be futile as soon as you pass to another browser. You have 3 options: 1) stay clear of complex layouts, keep it very very simple; 2) use a framework like the one I recommended above, it will help you with zooming and small/large page layout; or 3) don't care about having many visitors.

Comment: i am a new-bie here,i just started learning web,you were talking about something called frame work can you brief on that a bit.and any suggestions how to use.i will keep in mind rest of the instructions you gave me regarding visitors,

Comment: I'm sorry you'll have a long way to go. Read tutorials about these topics: HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, responsiveness. I tried to fix your code but it's a mess, your CSS is too complex. You can obtain the same with far less code if you know what you are doing. I'll delete this answer in an hour or two, because it does not help you at all.